# Values of Listbox with Seesaw

Tags: clojure, seesaw

is there any way i can get the values of a Listbox in seesaw as a collection, that Clojure can handle?

The most i've got was a JList, which Clojure can't handle.

/edit: To Clarify: For Example i want to get all of the Elements of a Listbox and `conj` a new Element onto them. But Because the return value of the listbox is a JList, Clojure naturally can't do that.

I can't seem to find any method to extract all Elements from the listbox.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't handle"? There should be no functionality you cannot access using the proper interop methods (ie. `(.getModel jl)`)

Comment: I added an example for clarity.

Comment: the JList docs mention that the list should not be modified - you would want to empty it and recreate the list anyway, even in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10780700/1552130). You can use [getModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getModel%28%29) method to get [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html). And then use `getElementAt` and `getSize` method to build array or list or whatever you want.

```
(def data (into-array String ["one" "two" "three" "four"]))
(def myList (JList. data))
(->> myList 
    .getModel 
    ((juxt identity (memfn getSize))) 
    ((fn [[a b]] (map #(.getElementAt a %) (range b)))) 
    (apply vector) (#(conj % "five")))
```